# location of rendered html files for django

Tags: django, apache, static, wsgi

I want to deploy my django development website onto server. But I have a hard time to understand the mechanism of wsgi. My understanding is the following: when user request a url, the wsgi.py will transfer the request to django. Then django will render the template html files and the output is a real html file. But I don't know where is this output html file. Will the server just send the html file to the user without saving it on the server?

I didn't configure the httpd.conf file correct now. I specified the location of wsgi.py file using WSGIScriptAlias. And I also specified where is the static files folder.  When I developed the website, it will search static folder under each app. Now I would think that the django will search for the static files according to the location specified in settings.py ? (e.g. /var/www/mysite.com/static/).

Comment: I searched the log file. It said: "search permissions are missing on a component of the path". Since I use apache:www in configure file. But the django folder is in my ec2-user account. So I replaced apache:www as ec2-user:ec2-user. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know where is this output html file. Will the server just send the html file to the user without saving it on the server?

That is correct, generated pages are not saved, they might be cached, but never actually "saved" anywhere.

> Now I would think that the django will search for the static files according to the location specified in settings.py ?

Static files are search for based on [how you configure the `staticfiles` app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean there is no need to configure DocumentRoot location, since almost all the html files are not static?

Comment: The default server wide DocumentRoot is generally fine, do not override it. Definitely do not set DocumentRoot to be where you project source code is because if you stuff up your Apache configuration you risk making your source code downloadable.